# How to disable MadExcept on command line?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, madexcept

I'm using Delphi 11 and using MadExcept to make things easier on development.

I have an automated procedure to deploy my apps using DCC32. I only want MadExcept to be enabled in debug / devolopment time, not on the release i send to my customers.

Is there a way to disable the setting below on the comand line, before compile with DCC32 ?

[image]

Comment: Just include ME in the dpr uses clause conditionally. You will regret this decision when a user finds a defect that you can't reproduce. My software would be so much worse if I excluded ME from the release build.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but wonder why, however, are you sure madExcept is enabled when you use the command line compiler?

From the [FAQ](http://help.madshi.net/madExceptFaq.htm):

> **6. Why does madExcept not work when I use command line compiling?**
>
> madExcept needs to patch your binary file. When compiling from inside the IDE, madExcept's integrated IDE wizard does that patching automatically. When using command line compiling, you need to manually invoke the patching process by starting the tool "madExceptPatch.exe" after having compiled your project. The tool is located in madExcept's "Tools" folder. Please add the parameter "-gd" to the command line when calling the compiler to make sure that a detailed map file is created.

Comment: Probably not enabled, but the code is included in the .EXE file (thus making it bigger). I suggest that you declare a conditional in your command line compilation that disables the inclusion of the MadExcept UNITs/Code.